# Next 13 Application - Deployment on Vercel behaving different from localhost, possible cache issue?

Tags: next.js, antd, vercel

I am building a Next 13 application and deploying to Vercel. A form in my application is using the [AntD TreeSelect](https://ant.design/components/tree-select) component. It is working fine on localhost. I am using the same component in several other forms in my application.

One particular form, the tree select component seems to be displaying additional values that do not belong there. I don't understand why or how those values are ending up in the list options. The only thing that I can think of is that perhaps there is a cache issue with Vercel.

I am new to Next13 and this is the first web application I have built on my own. Any help would be greatly and humbly appreciated.

I cannot share the full code, but I can provide some screenshots and snippets.

**Expected Behavior**: This example is working fine on local and Vercel

My application has account attributes as seen below

[image: Account attributes]

Each account attribute stores account attribute values. These values can be a flat list or hierarchical structure, which is why I am using the AntD Tree component. See working example below.
[image]

When I go the my edit form for a specific account attribute value, I see the correct available options for that account attribute. For example, the Cash Flow account attribute should not show any account attribute values for a different account attribute.

This example is working fine on both local and vercel.
[image]

I have one form that is showing different behavior only on Vercel. Same logic, just a different collection in my MongoDB. It works fine on local, but not on Vercel. Any clues?

I have a 'Level Attributes' page showing a list of level attributes, each with their own level attribute values. For example, Function, Country and Region.
[image]

When I go to the edit form on Vercel, I see this behavior, which is not correct. The select is showing options that belong to other level attributes.

[image]

Below is the correct behavior that works on localhost.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the issue. It actually fixed two different problems I was  having. This page uses a dynamic route with an 'id' slug.

```
level_attribute_value/64c9bde070062f167905bc78?paramId=64c9b8ead23ea0d8e9f381a5&paramName=Country
```

The route also has 2 searchParams. My original implementation had the following searchParams: 'id' and 'name'

I changed 'id' to paramId and seems to have fixed the issue. I am not sure if this is a bug but I did not see anywhere in the documentation about possible conflicts when using matching params and searchParams in a route.